# Repeating capture group with a regex pattern

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all, pcre, digits

I'm trying to get a list of products off a website including the individual product codes.
The product codes are 5 digit codes, the elements range in complexity from

```
<p>Part Number: 67001</p>

<p>Part Number: 50545 &ndash; 450g Cartridge 50525 - 2.5kg Tub 50520 - 20kg Pail 50555 - 55kg Drum 50575 *Indent - 175kg Drum</p>
```

Unfortunately, the 5 digit patterns are throughout the web pages, so I can't just use `/\d{5}/`

I'm after a regex that extracts only the 5 digits in the Part Number elements and not from the rest of the web page.

Something like: `/\<p\>Part\s*Number\:\s*((\d{5}) repeat this capture group n times)\<\/p\>/`

I know I can do it by breaking the page down in stages and applying one regex after another. eg

1st stage `/\<p\>Part\s*Number\:\s*.*?\<\/p\>/`
2nd stage `/\d{5}/`

But is it possible do it in one regex pattern and if so how?

Answer (score 2):

I am far wiser now than I was a year ago, so I have completely scrubbed my original advice.  The best / most reliable approach when trying to parse valid html is to use a dom parser.  XPath makes node/element hunting super easy.  A regex pattern is still an appropriate tool once you have disqualified `<p>` tags that do not contain the `Part Number` keyword.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/c2uA8))

```
$html = <<<HTML
<p>Zip Code: 99501</p>
<p>Part Number: 67001</p>
<p>Part Number: 98765 - 10000kg capacity</p>
<p>Some dummy/interfering text. Part Number: 12345</p>
<p>Zip Codes: 99501, 99524 , 85001 and 72201</p>
<p>Part Number: 50545 &ndash; 450g Cartridge 50525 - 2.5kg Tub 50520 - 20kg Pail 50555 - 55kg Drum 50575 *Indent - 175kg Drum</p>
HTML;

$partnos = [];

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query("//p[starts-with(., 'Part Number: ')]") as $node) {
    // echo "Qualifying text: {$node->nodeValue}\n";
    if (preg_match_all('~\b\d{5}\b~', $node->nodeValue, $matches)) {
        $partnos = array_merge($partnos, $matches[0]); //or array_push($partnos, ...$matches[0]);
    }
}
var_export($partnos);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '67001',
  1 => '98765',
  2 => '50545',
  3 => '50525',
  4 => '50520',
  5 => '50555',
  6 => '50575',
)
```

The xpath query says:

```
//p                  #find p tags at any level/position in the dom
[starts-with(.       #with a substring at the start of the node's text
, 'Part Number: ')]  #that literally matches "Part Number: "
```

The regex pattern uses [word boundary metacharacters](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) (`\b`) to differentiate part numbers from non-part numbers.  If you need the pattern to be adjusted because of some data that is not represented in your question, let me know and I'll offer further guidance.

Finally, I did flirt with a pure regex solution that incorporated `\G` to "continue" matching after `Part Number:` OR a previous match, but this type of pattern is a little bit harder to conceptualize and again a dom parser is a more stable tool versus regex when processing valid html.

Comment: I think you have answered my question. Your solution is an improvement. But it is not always possible to do it all in one regex if there is an unknown number of capture groups. Two stages is easy enough to implement. I will continue to do that.

Comment: @Kevin I received an upvote on this answer today which drew my attention back here.  I realized that my initial answer was not offering the superior wisdom that I have a year later.  Please review my completely rewritten answer and let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly you should just be able to do this:

`Part\sNumber:\s(\d{5})`

Given that your string contains all the `Part Number`, like demonstrated below:

```
<p>Part Number: 67001</p>

<p>Part Number: 50545 &ndash; 450g Cartridge 50525 - 2.5kg Tub 50520 - 20kg Pail 50555 - 55kg Drum 50575 *Indent - 175kg Drum</p>

<p>Part Number: 23425 - 55kg Drum 50575 *Indent - 175kg Drum</p>

<p>Part Number: 52232</p>
```

Comment: No, this regex only returns the first code after {<p>Part Number:} I want all codes before the ending{</p>}

Comment: If it's the only code that's 5 digits on the page, then you could just use `(\d{5})`.

Comment: Unfortunately the 5 digit patterns are throughout the web pages so I can't just use (\d{5})